# Can I use 0 and 1 values in quantilesExact

Tags: clickhouse

From the `quantile` function [documentation](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/reference/#agg_function-quantile):

> We recommend using a level value in the range of [0.01, 0.99]. Don't use a level value equal to 0 or 1 – use the min and max functions for these cases.

Does this also applies for `quantileExact` and `quantilesExact` functions?

In my experiments, I've found that `quantileExact(0) = min` and `quantileExact(1) = max`, but cannot be sure about it.

Comment: It applies for quantileExact and quantilesExact primarily. quantileExact(0) is always === min() and quantileExact(1) = max

Comment: Probably is some cases quantilesExact will be faster, e.g.  you need many quantilesExact(0,.10,.20,.30,.40...1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That recommendation is not about accuracy but about complexity of quantile*.
quantileExact is much much heavier than max min. 
See the time difference, min / max 8 times faster even on a small dataset.

```
create table Speed Engine=MergeTree order by X  
as select number X from numbers(1000000000);

SELECT min(X), max(X) FROM Speed;
┌─min(X)─┬────max(X)─┐
│      0 │ 999999999 │
└────────┴───────────┘
1 rows in set. Elapsed: 1.040 sec. Processed 1.00 billion rows, 8.00 GB (961.32 million rows/s., 7.69 GB/s.)

SELECT quantileExact(0)(X), quantileExact(1)(X) FROM Speed;
┌─quantileExact(0)(X)─┬─quantileExact(1)(X)─┐
│                   0 │           999999999 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
1 rows in set. Elapsed: 8.561 sec. Processed 1.00 billion rows, 8.00 GB (116.80 million rows/s., 934.43 MB/s.)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it is safe to use 0 and 1 values for `quantileExact` and `quantilesExact` functions.